# jQuery/JS order list by date string in file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, sorting, date

I have a list of files which are getting automatically grabbed from a folder and displayed on page in alphabetical order:

e.g

- A File Name 2015-11-01.pdf
- B File Name 2016-01-01.pdf
- C File Name 2015-12-01.pdf

I would like to sort them by using the date part of the filename so the are as so:

- B File Name 2016-01-01.pdf
- C File Name 2015-12-01.pdf
- A File Name 2015-11-01.pdf

HTML

```
<div class="wpdf_files_list_container">
<ul class="wpdf-list-style">
    <li class="clearfix active_alternative">
        <div class="row_filename">
        <p class="wpdf_file_name"><span class="wpdf_document_icon"><img src="document.png" class="img-responsive" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: block;"><img src ="document.png"></span>A File Name 2015-11-01.pdf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="A File Name 2015-11-01.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix deactive_alternative">
        <div class="row_filename">
        <p class="wpdf_file_name"><span class="wpdf_document_icon"><img src="document.png" class="img-responsive" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: block;"><img src ="document.png"></span>B File Name 2016-01-01.pdf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="B File Name 2016-01-01.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a></div>  
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix active_alternative">
        <div class="row_filename">
        <p class="wpdf_file_name"><span class="wpdf_document_icon"><img src="document.png" class="img-responsive" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: block;"><img src ="document.png"></span>C File Name 2015-12-01.pdf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="C File Name 2015-12-01.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a></div>      
    </li>

    ...
</ul>
</div>
```

Anyone have an example, not sure where to start?

Comment: Please show your actual HTML. We can't show you how to sort this without know *what* we're sorting

Comment: have you tried something already?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

this is the code to get sorted filenames. i assume u can carry on to arrange the html accordingly

since `yyyy-mm-dd` strings are both `ASCII checksum` and `chronologically` in the same order just comparing the strings world suffice. no date parsing required.

```
var sortedFilenames = filenames.sort(function(filename1, filename2) {
  return filename2) - filename1;
});
```

Comment: Since the dates are in year-month-date format, you don't need to convert to a Date or number; they'll sort correctly as strings.

Comment: ah @MikeMcCaughan makes sense